# Regex solution needed

Tags: regex

For these given sentences

```
//QAS Computer Object Add/Change/Rename/Move/Delete
//QAS Computer Object Add / Change / Rename / Move / Delete
//QAS Computer Object Add and Change
//QAS Computer Object Add / Change
//QAS Computer Object Add/Change
//Address Space Added/Removed To/From Send Connector
```

I need a regex that would extract all the groups of words and the words themselves from within these groups that are separated by `'/', ' / ', ' and '`.

So for given above sentences I'd get such the result

```
Add/Change/Rename/Move/Delete
Add / Change / Rename / Move / Delete
Add and Change
Add / Change
Add/Change
Added/Removed, To/From
```

Number of such groups within a sentence is at least 1.

Number of words that can create a group is at least 2.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: would be great if you had tried something...

Comment: What language are you working with? String.Split would be the obvious choice if it's available. Also, it's not exactly clear what you're after from the sample data. Do you want groups of words containing "/" or "and" in the middle, or do you want to use those tokens as delimiters for splitting up the sentences?

Comment: I think you need to use multiple regex. Once regex for all may be very hard to read. This `(\w+)/s*(\/|and)/s*(/w+)` may work for `//QAS Computer Object Add and Change, //QAS Computer Object Add / Change, and //QAS Computer Object Add/Change`. You may consider `split` on `/` for `//QAS Computer Object Add/Change/Rename/Move/Delete` inputs and split on `,` for the last case.

Comment: I tried all kind of things using \w+ and stuff, but could not write one regex to handle all situations. Language doesn't matter here, as Regex should be the same. but I'm using C#.

Comment: [Got speed ?](http://regex101.com/r/vP4hZ5)

Comment: Thanks HamZa, that works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why HamZa posted that as a comment instead of an answer.  Here is the Regex for anyone who is interested.

```
(?:\w+\s?(?:\/|and)\s?)+\w+
```